# Is it possible to create and edit apps using a tablet, be it iOS, Android or Windows?

Tags: powerapps

I would like to know if it is possible to use a tablet to create apps via **power apps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it won't be as easy as with a desktop/laptop computer. If you use the tablet's browser to navigate to make.powerapps.com you should be able to log in and create apps, but the screen will be smaller, and you may need to edit some properties directly (instead of doing what would normally be done with a mouse).